# How do I use my RX 5700 with Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: drivers, 19.04, amd-graphics, mesa

I have an Ryzen 3700x and the RX 5700. There appears to be no hardware acceleration, and I seem to be using software-rendering for everything.
I have recently uninstalled the proprietary AMDGPU pro drivers and upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 from 18.04, installed the 5.3-rc3 kernel, and started using oibaf's PPA. Moving back to Ubuntu 18.04 + AMDGPU pro drivers is unwanted because support for the Valve Index doesn't appear to be that good. Is there anything I can do other than wait a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a guide on how to use RX 5700 (XT) on 19.04 with open source drivers here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425799
If you already have oibaf's PPA and 5.3 kernel installed all you need is to download firmware files and copy them into /lib/firmware/amdgpu

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install amdgpu-pro on Ubuntu 18.04 and then upgrade to 19.04
with no issues.  The first time I tried it, I installed it directly to 19.04
and that did not work.

I was able to install the amdgpu-pro drivers for my RX 5700 in Ubuntu 18.4, 
then upgraded t